# How do you manipulate GUID's when programming C or C++ in Windows?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, guid

How do you manipulate GUID's when doing Windows programming in C or C++?

Comment: Don't answer a question in a question.

Answer (score 5):

Under Win32 if you want to manipulate GUID's you can use the UuidXXX() Network/RPC functions:

- UuidCompare()
- UuidCreate()
- UuidCreateNil()
- UuidCreateSequential()
- UuidEqual()
- UuidFromString()
- UuidHash()
- UuidIsNil()
- UuidToString()

Answer (score 0):

I use boost::uuid : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/uuid/index.html
That way it is guaranteed to still work if I port my application on another plaftorm.